# Apache arrow js toArray() returns array of Proxy objects instead of data

Tags: javascript, apache-arrow

So I'm using apache arrow with Javascript. I'd like to simply retrieve the arrow file from an endpoint and display the data. The problem is when I run `toArray()` on the arrow data file, it returns a Proxy object for each piece of data:

```
import { tableFromIPC } from 'apache-arrow'

const arrowTable = await tableFromIPC(arrowResults)
const output = arrowTable.toArray()
console.log(output)
```

[image]

To get around this I have some logic to convert each object to its equivalent key/value pair. This works, but it's terribly slow:

```
const output = [...arrowTable].map((c) =>
            Object.keys(c).reduce(
                (acc, k) => (k ? { ...acc, [k]: `${c[k]}` } : acc),
                {} as CellInfo
            )
        )
```

[image]

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you care that they're Proxy objects? What are you trying to do with them that doesn't work correctly because they're Proxies?

Comment: Side note: You can do a shallow clone of the own enumerable properties (what your code is currently doing) much more simply: `.map((c) => Object.assign({}, c) as CellInfo)` or `.map((c) => ({...c} as CellInfo))`.